# Error in console using UIAlertAction Xcode 7.3 beta

Tags: swift, uialertview, uialertaction

I am trying to print the error to the user using alertview.
Here is my code :::

```
if error != nil{
 let DisplayAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!!", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: .Alert)
 DisplayAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
}
```

When I run the code I see the following in the console and I do not see any alert displayed to user.

*"Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior"*

What should i do to fix this issue.? Pls help. 
Thanks !!!

Comment: That means that you are trying to present the alert on a view controller that is currently loading other views. Can you share more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have forgot to present the alert

```
if error != nil{
    let DisplayAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!!", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: .Alert)
     DisplayAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(DisplayAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: If it worked, consider marking this as the answer. Thanks